# Unable to get Tessallation shader working

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I've just started following OpenGL SuperBible 7th ed, and translating the examples into LWJGL, but have become stuck on the tessellation shader. In the following program there is the line "   //IF THESE TWO LINES..." if the following two lines are commented out then the vertex and fragment shaders work but when the *control.tess.glsl* and *eval.tess.glsl* are included then the triangle no longer renders.

I've uploaded my program onto [github](https://github.com/quaternion2/Ch3VertPipeline.git) but will reproduce the code here as well:

```
package com.ch3vertpipeline;

public class App {      
   public static void main(String [] args){
      LwjglSetup setup = new LwjglSetup();
      setup.run();
   }
}


package com.ch3vertpipeline;

import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public class LwjglSetup {

    private long window;
    private int vertex_shader;
    private int fragment_shader;
    private int tess_control_shader;
    private int tess_evaluation_shader;
    private int program;
    private int vertex_array_object;

    public LwjglSetup() {
    }

    private void init() {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }
        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
            }
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try (MemoryStack stack = stackPush()) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");
        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void loop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();//Critical
        System.out.println("OpenGL Verion: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        this.compileShader();
        vertex_array_object = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);


        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            double curTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0;
            double slowerTime = curTime;//assigned direcly but I was applying a factor here
            final float colour[] = {
                (float) Math.sin(slowerTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
                (float) Math.cos(slowerTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
                0.0f, 1.0f};

            glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, colour);

            glUseProgram(program);

            final float attrib[] = {
                (float) Math.sin(slowerTime) * 0.5f,
                (float) Math.cos(slowerTime) * 0.6f,
                0.0f, 0.0f};

            //glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3);//this is the default so is unneeded
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            glVertexAttrib4fv(0, attrib);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vertex_array_object);
        glDeleteProgram(program);
    }

    private String readFileAsString(String filename) {
        String next = new Scanner(LwjglSetup.class.getResourceAsStream(filename), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println("readFileAsString: " + next);
        return next;
    }

    private void compileShader() {
        //int program;
        //NEW CODE
        //create and compile vertex shader
        String vertShaderSource = readFileAsString("/vert.glsl");
        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vertShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
        //check compilation
        if (glGetShaderi(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //create and compile fragment shader
        String fragShaderSource = readFileAsString("/frag.glsl");
        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, fragShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
        //check compilation
        if (glGetShaderi(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //create and compile tessellation shader
        String tessControlShaderSource = readFileAsString("/control.tess.glsl");
        tess_control_shader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(tess_control_shader, tessControlShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(tess_control_shader);
        //check compilation
        if (glGetShaderi(tess_control_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tess_control_shader));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //create and compile tessellation shader
        String tessEvaluationShaderSource = readFileAsString("/eval.tess.glsl");
        tess_evaluation_shader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(tess_evaluation_shader, tessEvaluationShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(tess_evaluation_shader);
        //check compilation
        if (glGetShaderi(tess_evaluation_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tess_evaluation_shader));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //create program and attach it
        program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
        //IF THESE TWO LINES ARE COMMENTED PROGRAM WORKS...although there
        //is no tessallation...
        glAttachShader(program, tess_control_shader);
        glAttachShader(program, tess_evaluation_shader);

        glLinkProgram(program);
        //check link       
        if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_LINK_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        glValidateProgram(program);
        if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        //delete shaders as the program has them now
        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
        glDeleteShader(tess_control_shader);
        glDeleteShader(tess_evaluation_shader);
        //return program;
    }
}
```

**vert.glsl**

```
#version 440 core

//'offset' is an input vertex attribute
layout (location=0) in vec4 offset;
layout (location=1) in vec4 color;

out vec4 vs_color;

void main(void)
{
    const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](   vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),
                                        vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),
                                        vec4( 0.25,  0.25, 0.5, 1.0));
   //Add 'offset' to hour hard-coded vertex position
    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;

    //Output a fixed value for vs_color
    vs_color = color;
}
```

**frag.glsl**

```
#version 440 core 

in vec4 vs_color;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color = vs_color;
}
```

**control.tess.glsl**

```
#version 440 core

layout (vertices=3) out;

void main(void)
{
    //Only if I am invocation 0
    if (gl_InvocationID == 0){
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;
    }
    //Everybody copies their input to their output?
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

**eval.tess.glsl**

```
#version 440 core

layout (triangles,  equal_spacing, cw) in;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position) + 
                  (gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position) + 
                  (gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position);
}
```

Finally, if it helps here is some version information, which is printed at the start of the application:

```
Hello LWJGL 3.1.5 build 1!
OpenGL Verion: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.107
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

When you draw something with tessellation, you are drawing patches, not triangles. Hence, you have to specify `GL_PATCHES`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 3);
```

> //Everybody copies their input to their output?

The reason is that the input vertices and output vertices of the tessellation control shader are not related to each other. The input vertices are taken from the input stream, i.e. your vertex buffers (after being processed by the vertex shader). Their number is specified by the `GL_PATCH_VERTICES` parameter. Each invocation takes this number of vertices from the buffer. The output vertices are kept internally in the pipeline. Their number is specified by the `layout` directive. This number can be different from the number of input vertices. They can also have different attributes. I find it more intuitive to think of these vertices as pieces of data instead of actual vertices with a geometric meaning. In some cases, this interpretation might make sense, but definitely not in all.

Comment: I swear I tried GL_PATCHES... regardless making that change makes everything happy. Thank you, more time than I would like to admit was spent staring at this tiny program.

Comment: Also I forgot that comment was in the code, but thank you for answering the second part. I copied that comment from the author "//Everybody..." but I added the question mark because I didn't understand it but now do.